# How to replace all occurences of a text in vim where the characters in the text are unicode characters?

Tags: vim

How to replace all occurences of a text in vim where the characters in the text are unicode characters, for example snippet

```
each¬ 4 ▸ ▸ <% ${1:collection}.each do |${2:member}| -%>¬ 5 ▸ ▸ ▸ ▸ ${3}¬ 6 ▸ ▸ <% end -%>¬
```

I want to replace all the `▸ ▸` occurences with empty string, I tried `s/▸ ▸//g` and even the unicode for `▸` which is U+25B8 but doesn't seem to work, or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways. If you want to match *all non-ASCII characters*, that'll be `[^\x00-\x7F]`.

For a particular one (say, U+25B8; the `ga` command is useful to tell you the current character's code), you can:

- just `y`ank it, and insert it in the command-line search via `<C-R>"` (that's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, followed by <kbd>"</kbd>)
- insert it via `<C-V>u25b8` in the command-line
- use the special `\%u25B8` atom

Comment: Does the `V` key need to be a `R`?